# Factor of 2 in the Rabi frequency

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-optics, density-operator, dipole-moment, rabi-model

This is a question about a strange literature discrepancy which I can't seem to resolve for myself.

In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Bloch_equations) on the Maxwell-Bloch equations, the Rabi frequency is defined as

$$\Omega = \frac{1}{\hbar}\underline{d}\cdot\underline{E}\,,$$

where $\underline{d}$ is the dipole moment of the transition. The density matrix equations of motion are then (only writing out for one of the elements and omitting the decay term):
$$\frac{d}{dt} \rho_{eg} = i \frac{\Omega}{2} (\rho_{gg} - \rho_{ee}) \,. $$

Essentially, my question is: **Where does that divided by 2 come from?**

Let me elaborate: The Hamiltonian in the $\underline{E}\cdot\underline{r}$ gauge within the dipole approximation should be $\underline{E}\cdot\underline{d}\,|e\rangle\langle g|+h.c.$, where the dipole moment is $\underline{d}=\langle g|\underline{r}|e\rangle$. Deriving the density matrix equation of motion with $\rho_{eg} = \langle e|\rho|g\rangle$ (and similarly for the other elements), I get the above equations but *without* the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. Also the textbook by Scully&Zubairy seems to agree with me (Equation 5.3.24 in the 1997 Edition).

The wikipedia version seems to also be used elsewhere though, I have seen it in a couple of papers. So this issue is likely a difference in convention. However, I don't really see where a convention could enter here. The dipole moment is a pretty clear-cut quantity. One can have different conventions if one uses the Pauli $\sigma$-operators, but I have intentionally written the above in terms of *states*, which seem to allow no room for a convention.

Another option is that I am doing something terribly wrong, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from the equation
$$
\cos(\omega t) = \frac{e^{i\omega t} + e^{-i\omega t}}{2}
$$
In the original equation you have
$$
E = E_0 \cos(\omega t)
$$
When you put the interaction Hamiltonian into Schrodinger's equation you get a term which in matrix notation is
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & E_0 \cos(\omega t)\\
E_0 \cos(\omega t) & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
It is then common to adopt either an interaction picture or else in general a frame rotating at some angular frequency
$\omega_0$. Skipping the proof, the interaction term then becomes
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & e^{i \omega_0 t} E_0 \cos(\omega t)\\
e^{-i \omega_0 t} E_0 \cos(\omega t) & 0 \end{array} \right)
=
\frac{E_0}{2}
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 
e^{i (\omega_0+\omega) t}  +  e^{i (\omega_0-\omega) t}
\\
e^{i (-\omega_0+\omega) t}  +  e^{i (-\omega_0-\omega) t}
& 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
The terms involving $\omega_0 + \omega$ typically rotate very much more quickly than those involving $\omega_0 - \omega$. In that case we can make the *rotating wave approximation* which involves dropping the fast-evolving terms, leaving
$$
\frac{E_0}{2}
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 
 +  e^{i (\omega_0-\omega) t} \\
e^{i (-\omega_0+\omega) t}  & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
The rotating-wave approximation is so widely used that people sometimes seem to think it is exact, and does not need to be mentioned. In fact it is not exact and a more thorough analysis reveals what is being left out. A quick rule of thumb is that it only gives a reasonable approximation when the Rabi flopping is itself slow compared to the other frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for the great (and quick...) answer! I think this is the solution. In the context of the density matrix equations of motion, the difference would then be that one is in the interaction picture with the rotating wave approximation already included and the other is in the Schrödinger picture. So that perfectly fits with my suspicion that it is a kind of convention. I'll reflect a bit more and likely accept your answer afterwards.